# How to run a preview on private instance?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

Our pipeline fetch data from internet.
The preview mode doesn't work on my **private** cloud data fusion instance, I have a timeout each time.
The same jobs work when deployed.
Note  I am obliged to have a **private** instance.

How can I get a preview that connects to the internet?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: what's wrong with Arthur's question @willcrack ?

Answer (score 0):

To successfully run preview on a private instance, you need to setup VPC peering to the tenant project. For more documentation on how to do this, you can see the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip#set_up_network_peering

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the VPC peering is already active but the preview does not work.

Comment: any error you can provide from the logs of the preview run?

Comment: Only timeout each time

Comment: Are there any firewall rule blocking or needs to be enabled to talk to the tenant project?

Comment: same case here trying to reach a Salesforce source and using a shared VPC, even I tried using a Cloud NAT for testing but It didn't make the trick, any workaround?